# Rest service ambigious path

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

In my rest service I have 2 methods like the following:

```
    @POST
    @Path("{groupId}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public DataPointTO addToGroup(@PathParam("groupId") String groupId){}

    @POST
    @Path("/testing")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response testing(){}
```

When I tried to go to /root/testing, it calls `addToGroup` instead. It thinks that I am trying to add something to a group id of "`testing`".  How can I tell it to go to /testing when the rest call is `/root/testing`, instead of `addToGroup()`? `GroupId` can be any letters or numbers.

Comment: Is groupId set to "testing"?

Comment: Set request header `Accept: text/plain`

Comment: Also what JAX-RS implementation are you using? This is pretty weird behavior. According to the spec, these these two path expressions aren't ambiguous. The latter is more specific and should take precidence. It would make sense though if for some reason you set the `Accept` header to `application/xml`

Comment: I think it might be the new resteasy upgrade that caused this? @peeskillet

Comment: How are you consuming the service? Have you checked the request headers that are being sent out. You need to find out what the `Accept` header is.